# How to embed ssrs iframe content into html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, reporting-services

For some security concern, I have to get the SSRS address along with the Authorization header. So I used the ajax method to get ssrs content. But how can I embed the data into html?

Thanks in advance!

[image: SSRS]
[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

Actually I could not go down with this path because I found out even I embedded this SSRS html page, I still could not append the authorization for each requests sending further within the iframe. So the ssrs scripts will always show 401 authorized.

I ended up adding authorization cookies in the browser and proxy pass the cookie in the nginx server . I know this is definitely not the best practice, or even a good practice, so you're more than welcome to offer your suggestions.